# Share Conversion between Different Finite Fields

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, finite-field, garbled-circuits, function-evaluation

Let us have any linear secret sharing scheme (LSSS) that works on some field $Z_{p}$, where p is some prime or a power of a prime e.g., Shamir Secret Sharing, Additive secret Sharing. 
The problem at hand is simple, for any secret shared value in $Z_{p}$, is it possible to convert it (and its shares) to elements on $Z_{q}$, where q could be either greater or smaller than p? Note that **I do not need** conversion from $Z_{2^n}$ to $Z_{2}$.

I am aware of the results on [PRSS](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-30576-7_19), and well as in this [2008](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/221.pdf) work, however the former does not address field conversion, and the latter, have explanations that are not clear nor it offers perfect security.

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: There is a way to do share conversion from binary to arithmetic and vice-versa using this paper: http://thomaschneider.de/papers/DSZ15.pdf

Comment: @Dragos, as I pointed out on the explanation of the problem I 'm not interested on $Z_{2}$ to $Z_{2^r}$ conversions. Thanks anyways!

Comment: For me, arithmetic means $Z_p$. You can use the method above by first converting from $Z_p \rightarrow Z_2$ and then from $Z_2 \rightarrow Z_q$.

Comment: @Dragos. My inputs are bounded by the conversion target, if I do any transformation to a smaller field, let say $Z_{2}$ I would loose information (or be forced to use bit decomposition which I also want to avoid). This is why I cannot use $Z_{2}$, as I pointed out. Any idea is welcome!

Comment: I see..Even converting shares from $Z_p \rightarrow Z_2^{r}$ is a hard problem - at least I have encountered it several times and don't know how to solve it efficiently other than bit decompose and simulate the binary circuit in $Z_p$.

Comment: @Dragos... Btw.... Are you from Bristol's group? that Dragos?